# Marketing cloud SSJS DE Query Preview fails

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to query a simple DE using ssjs. There is nothing extra ordinary in this one as this is fairly simple.

somehow the preview is failing

```html
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load('core', '1.1.1');
  var postData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
  var form = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(postData);
  var Operator_Value = form['Operator_Value'];
  var Operation_Value = form['Operation_Value'];
  var User_Value = form['User_Value'];
  var DE = form['Dataextension'];
  try{
    var myDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);
    var filter = {
      Property:Operator_Value,SimpleOperator:Operation_Value,Value:User_Value};
    var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    Write(Stringify(data));
  }
  catch(error){
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
  }
</script>
```

The response i get when i preview is

error: {"message":"Object expected: Retrieve","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: Retrieve\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

not sure what i am doing wrong . This DE is present in Enterprise Shared BU and i am running this script in Enterprise BU .

I am using customer key of DE. Even if i hardcode all parameter which i get from form, still same error

[image]

```html
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load('core', '1.1.1');
  var postData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
  var form = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(postData);
  var Operator_Value = form['Operator_Value'];
  var Operation_Value = form['Operation_Value'];
  var User_Value = form['User_Value'];
  var DE = form['Dataextension'];
  try{
    var myDE = DataExtension.Init('Ext_Customer');
    var filter = {
      Property:'ContactId',SimpleOperator:'equals',Value:'003ABCD1003'};
    var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
    Write(Stringify(data));
  }
  catch(error){
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
  }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still do get the error , but i read on some blogs to publish even when preview fails

that approach seems to be working.